# Is there a name for the followin 'norm' on vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a real vector space of dimension $n$. Define a "norm" by $$\|v\| = \frac{\sum v_i}{n} - \min v_i.$$ So the "norm" is the difference between the average value and the minimum value. It is not actually a norm as it is zero on all vectors which are entry-wise equal. My question is if this comes up in any natural contexts.

Comment: It might help us to know what inspired you to write this expression. (Also, I wonder if this is actually a norm on some quotient space of $V$ - like if we quotient by the subspace of vectors $(t,t,\ldots,t)$)

Comment: It arises quite indirectly in algebraic geometry, I would like to know if it comes up somewhere in linear algebra.